# 3 hours layover at Haneda airport to US

Tags: visas, transit, japan, filipino-citizens, hnd

I am a Philippine passport holder travelling to US via Haneda. I only have a 3-hour layover in Haneda. From Manila I will be taking PH Airlines and from Haneda to US I will be taking AA (American Airlines).

Do I need a transit visa at Haneda airport?

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to go out of the airport then you need a visa. For a 3 hour layover, I suggest that you stay at the airport because sometimes flights are delayed and your 3 hours layover may become 2 hours.

In the same time you need atleast 1 hour in an average to find your connecting flight gate and prepare to board the plane.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=PH&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&selDest=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20destination%28s%29%20above&TR=JP&selTrans=Japan&user=PEARL&subuser=PEARL), the database used by Airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Holders of onward tickets for a max.
>   transit time of 72 hours through Tokyo Haneda
>   (HND) or Osaka Kansai (KIX).

So if the trip is in one booking, you do **not** need a visa

Answer (score 0):

Check haneda custom [website](http://www.haneda-airport.jp/inter/en/faq/faq_transit.html). They actually have a section with Visa.
It says that you should check with your embassy about restrictions and such.

Also I found a [PDF](http://www.ph.emb-japan.go.jp/files/000232573.pdf) from Philippine embassy regarding traveling to japan. regarding to this country passport it says:

> 1. Philippine Passport
>      •      Broken  passport  is  not  accepted.  Passports  must  be  signed  and  must  have  at  least  two  (2)  blank visa pages.

Make sure before buying your plane ticket that your trip includes visa for transit. Otherwise this could be problematic.

So if you stay in the transit zone you shouldn't have any visa trouble :)

Hope this helps

Comment: There's no use sending the OP to that website because all it says is "Check with your embassy". It is also not the customs website, it's the airport website.

Comment: Sorry, I try to help as much as I can @JanDoggen